# What does this warning mean? (fancyhdr and headheight)

Tags: errors, fancyhdr

My LaTeX file compiles fine. However, in reading my `.log` file, I see many repeated instances of

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small
```

Looking for it in google, I found some 'fixes', but first I'd like to know what the error is about.

What is `fancyhdr`? What is `\headheight`? What does the error mean?

Comment: Just add in the preamble the minimum measure that you advise. For example:
```
\setlength\headheight{24pt}
```

Comment: It’s pretty common for people to start by copying someone else’s preamble—or even many different ones. My advice is usually to try to write a minimal template with only the packages you actually use. You’ll get fewer bugs that way.

Comment: @Davislor: People are often given a style file from their publisher or from an academic journal. They have to use that, and it's then reasonable for them to ask for help understanding it.

Comment: @BenCrowell You are correct. If that’s the situation, my advice would not apply.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

First of all, this is just a *warning*, which is different from an *error*.

- [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) is a package that

  > pro­vides ex­ten­sive fa­cil­i­ties, both for con­struct­ing head­ers and foot­ers, and for con­trol­ling their use (for ex­am­ple, at times when LATEX would au­to­mat­i­cally change the head­ing style in use).

  (from the [`fancyhdr` README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/README))
- `\headheight` is the (vertical) height associated with the header of the page. Where is this located at on the page? Here's a schematic (from the [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf)):

  [image]

  The notation in the above image corresponds to the `geometry` settings, but is similar to the lengths used by `fancyhdr`.
- The *warning* mentions that the space currently allocated for the header is too small and should be enlarged. A more comprehensive view of the message will actually tell you what the suggested *minimum* height should be.

  You can ignore this warning, but page layouts will be adjusted by `fancyhdr` automatically and therefore differ from one page to the next. Here's an example that highlights this:

  [image]

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhead[C]{\rule{.5\textwidth}{4\baselineskip}}% Add something BIG in the header

  \begin{document}

  \lipsum[1-10]

  \end{document}
  ```

  Note how the header rule remains at the same height from one page to the next (the red arrow). However, the first line of text on the page is pushed down immediately following the incorrect `\headheight` page. `fancyhdr` adjusted this manually, as noted by the *warning* text:

  ```
  Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
   Make it at least 51.60004pt.
   We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
   This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
  ```

  Correcting for this we add

  ```
  \setlength{\headheight}{52pt}% ...at least 51.60004pt
  ```

  to the preamble:

  [image]

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhead[C]{\rule{.5\textwidth}{4\baselineskip}}% Add something BIG in the header
  \setlength{\headheight}{52pt}% ...at least 51.60004pt

  \begin{document}

  \lipsum[1-10]

  \end{document}
  ```

<sub>Note, load or place your `geometry` settings *before* loading `fancyhdr`/selecting `\pagestyle{fancy}`.</sub>

Comment: you do the Oppostite of your note : settings before pagestyle!

Comment: @qrtLs: I specifically refer to [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry) settings, which is not used in my code.

Comment: Note if you come to this answer because you are writing in Markdown (or RMarkdown) and using pandoc to convert to TeX, you can include headheight = 52pt in your YAML underneath of your geometry: line (make sure to tab in once!)