# How to add page numbering to CurVe CV

Tags: header-footer, luatex, cv, curve-class

I'm editing this costumized CurVe CV:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-customised-curve-cv/mvmbhkwsnmwv

Sadly I'm not able to add any page numbering.
How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

using

```
\geometry{includefoot}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{\hfill\thepage\hfill}
\renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{\hfill\thepage\hfill}
\makeatother
```

---

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This CV example/template is based on my own
% CV which I (lamely attempted) to clean up, so that
% it's less of an eyesore and easier for others to use.
%
% LianTze Lim (liantze@gmail.com)
% 16 September, 2016
%
\documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,11pt,british]{curve}

% Uncomment to enable Chinese; needs XeLaTeX
% \usepackage{ctex}

\usepackage{settings}

% Change the fonts if you want
\ifxetexorluatex % If you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  %% Warning: EB Garamond contains no bold!! Substituting for Junicode Bold, but *may not look nice nor consistent*!!
%   \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=5},BoldFont=Junicode Bold]{EB Garamond}
  %% Charis SIL's rather nice, actually.
  \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=5}]{Charis SIL}
  \setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Fira Sans}
  \setmonofont{Inconsolata}
\else % If you're using pdfLaTeX or latex
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[tracking=smallcaps]{microtype}
  \usepackage{fbb}
  \usepackage[type1]{cabin}
  \usepackage[varqu,varl]{zi4}
  \useosf  %% Comment out if you prefer lining figures rather than old style figures
\fi
\usepackage{csquotes}

%% Only needed if you want a Publication List
\addbibresource{own-bib.bib}

%% Specify your last name and first name (as given in the .bib) to automatically bold your own name in the publications list. One caveat: You need to write \bibnamedelima where there's a space in your name for this to work properly for now...
\myname{Lim}{Lian\bibnamedelima Tze}
% \myname{d'Andrimont}{Raphaël}

% Change the page margins if you want
% \geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}

% Change the colours if you want
% \definecolor{SwishLineColour}{HTML}{00FFFF}
% \definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{0000CC}

% Change the item prefix marker if you want
% \prefixmarker{$\diamond$}

%% Photo is only shown if "fullonly" is included
\includecomment{fullonly}
% \excludecomment{fullonly}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\leftheader{%
  {\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily Lim Lian Tze, Ph.D.}

  \makefield{\faEnvelopeO}{\texttt{liantze@gmail.com}}
  \makefield{\faTwitter}{\texttt{@liantze}}

  \makefield{\faGlobe}{\url{http://liantze.penguinattack.org/}}

  \makefield{\faLinkedinSquare}
  {\url{http://www.linkedin.com/in/limliantze/}}
}

\rightheader{~}
\begin{fullonly}
\photo[r]{photo}
\photoscale{0.13}
\end{fullonly}

\geometry{includefoot}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{\hfill\thepage\hfill}
\renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{\hfill\thepage\hfill}
\makeatother


\title{Curriculum Vitae}

\begin{document}
\makeheaders[c]

\makerubric{employment}
\makerubric{education}

% If you're not a researcher nor an academic, you probably don't have any publications; delete this line.
%% Sometimes when a section can't be nicely modelled with the \entry[]... mechanism; hack our own and use \input NOT \makerubric
\input{publications}

\makerubric{skills}
\makerubric{misc}

\makerubric{referee}
% \input{referee-full}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it work as intended. There is just a little problem: in some pages the footer is way to close to the text. 

See here for an example: https://i.imgur.com/Gg6C7mv.png

Is there a way to put a minimum distance?

Comment: @AlbertoBragagnolo Can you show the code of a document that reproduces the problem? I don't have the problem in the code posted in the answer.

Comment: Hi @jackfrost. The issue disappeared after a couple of hous/days. I don't know how or why.

Comment: Going forward, if someone else wants to add spacing between the header and/or footer and the page body, add `\setlength{\topskip}{length}` and/or `\setlength{\footskip}{length}` after the `\renewcommand` and before `\makeatother` in the MWE. The _length_ parameter can be any LaTeX unit of measure.

Answer (score -1):

You may use the code showed in *user187808*'s answer, and then add the line

```
\setlength{\footskip}{25pt}
```

to set up distance between the footer and the last line of page.
Please see further in this link: [What does this warning mean? (fancyhdr and headheight)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327285/what-does-this-warning-mean-fancyhdr-and-headheight)

Comment: This solution requires using `fancyhdr`, which isn't part of @user187808 's MWE