# Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt)

Tags: fancyhdr

I used the following

> ```
> \usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
> \usepackage{fancyhdr}
> \pagestyle{fancy}
> \fancyhead{}
> \fancyhead[RO,LE]{Systemic Crisis: Visualizing Vulnerability}
> \fancyfoot{}
> \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
> \fancyfoot[LO,CE]{chapter \thechapter}
> \fancyfoot[CO,RE]{Raisul Islam}
> \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
> \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
> ```

I am writing my thesis. i have the warning

> Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): Make it
>   at least 14.49998pt. We now make it that large for the rest of the
>   document. This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.

Please help

Comment: just do as it says: `\setlength\headheight{15pt}`

Comment: For a more in depth explanation see the answer to the following (duplicate?) question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/327285/134144

Comment: This fixed the issue....Thank you so much